# How can I change File Info in Ajax File Upload Control ,Asp.net(VB)?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, webforms

I am creating a drag file upload by using Ajax File Upload Control in Asp.net(VB).
I want to show file name, uploaded datetime, file size when I dragged into panel.
How can I do for that setting?
I could change the text for droparea like

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            
            Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_Pending = "保留中";
            Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_Remove = "削除";
            Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_Uploaded = "アップロード済";
            Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_Uploading = "アップロード中";
            Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_UploadedPercentage = "アップロード中 {0} %";
            Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_Upload = "アップロード";

            document.getElementsByClassName
            $(".ajax__fileupload_dropzone").text("ここにファイルをドロップ");

            document.getElementsByClassName
            $(".ajax__fileupload_uploadbutton").text("アップロード");
            
        });
```

But I don't know how to change file info display.

This is my drag form and I want to change from `application/pdf` to `uploaded datetime`

[image]

Comment: see my new comments and part 2 - I outline how you can display the information about the files up-loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really display the "time" of up-load until the user starts.

You ALREADY can see the file size in your screen cap, so why the need for that?

you have:

[image]

so in above, you see the file name, you see the file size.

However, until such time you hit up-load and start up-loading files, you don't know yet the up-load time as of yet, do you?

So, when you hit up-load files, then each file selected will be up-loaded, and in the server side (code behind), you have this:

```
Protected Sub AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(sender As Object, e As AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs) Handles AjaxFileUpload1.UploadComplete

    Dim strFileSave As String
    strFileSave = Server.MapPath("~/Content/" & e.FileName)
    AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(strFileSave)

    ' now code to add say to a database table of files up-loaded.

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Dim strSQL = "INSERT INTO MyUpoadFiles (FileName, UpLoadTime, Size, User_id) " &
                     "VALUES (@File, @Time,@Size, @User)"

        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            With cmdSQL.Parameters
                .Add("@File", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = e.FileName
                .Add("@Time", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Date.Now
                .Add("@Size", SqlDbType.Int).Value = e.FileSize
                .Add("@User", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Membership.GetUser.ProviderUserKey
            End With
            cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using


End Sub
```

Now, when ALL files are up-loaded, then the server side even UpLoadComplete all will fire, and THEN you can take the above list/table and display the files up-loaded along with the FileName, size, and time.

But, you really don't have the ability to display the file information such as what time until such time you uploaded the file and then have the time, right?

## Edit:

Perhaps the idea above was not all that clear. What I am suggesting is that you have the up-loader on the page.

So, say we drop in this markup:

```
        <div style="width:40%;padding:25px">
        <ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" 
            OnClientUploadCompleteAll="MyCompleteAll"  ChunkSize="16384" />

            <asp:Button ID="cmdDone" runat="server" Text="Done" CssClass="btn" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
            <script>
                function MyCompleteAll() {
                    $('#cmdDone').click()
                  }
            </script>
            <asp:GridView ID="Gfiles" runat="server" CssClass="table"></asp:GridView>
        </div>
```

And note how we use the client side all done click.

So, we now have this:

[image]

We hit upload, and now we see this:

[image]

Now we should (need to) hide the Done button - we have the upload clicking on that done button for us.

So that button in theory should become this to hide it:

```
 <asp:Button ID="cmdDone" runat="server" Text="Done"
   style="display:none" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
```

And the code for that button is this:

```
Protected Sub cmdDone_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdDone.Click

    Dim rstFiles As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Dim strSQL As String = "select FileName, UpLoadTime, Size, User_id from MyUpLoadFiles"
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            rstFiles.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using

    Gfiles.DataSource = rstFiles
    Gfiles.DataBind()

    ' hide up-loader
    AjaxFileUpload1.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Albert, Thank you for your answer. I still can't work this part cuz I need to do other project but I will try your answer as soon as I can. Your answer really pointed out for my project. Thx you so much. You save me alot.

Comment: Hello, I tried with your code and when I hit upload button , data can insert in table . Then I made a select command and set in datatable but my gridview can't show totally and didn't hide ajaxfileupload field. I did debug and my gridview had data from my db table.

Comment: Well, as we up-load files, they are added to that table. but when ALL files (or maybe you just selected one file) are up-loaded, then we have that "done" button. I of course don't want users to have to click that done button, so note how we wired up the "compile all event" CLIENT SIDE with some JavaScript to click that button for us. I mean, for testing, just let the file (or files) up-load. And then click on that one button that runs the code behind to now take the values from the data base table and display in the grid. As noted, we will need to add the user_id to that table.

Comment: So I did not want users to have to click that button when done - that's what the small amount of JavaScript does - I did assume you have jQuery available on that page (don't we all????). And once you verfied that this works, then we will hide that "done" button. But, if you don't wire up that js code to click that button (since we MUST HAVE a full post-back occur!!! - you NEED that post back. You can't put the grid display code in the server side ajax file up-load event - you MUST click a button for the post-back. So follow the above markup with the js code to click the button.

Comment: Note in above, how the code to dispay the grid is in the commadn done button click. So to be clear, we can't put the grid display code in any of the ajax file up load control events. We need that seperate button. For testing, just drop a plane jane button on the web page. After your up-load is done, then click on that button to run the display grid code. Once you get that working, then add the above js code to automatic click that button. And then add a a style "display:none" to hide that button from the user.